# iOS IAP Receipt Validation

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have an app that needs to use IAP. I tested with sample code and sandbox user and the transactions are made successfully. Where I cannot proceed is the receipt validation part. Firstly - the app uses consumable products /tokens/ - somewhere I read no need for validation in this case. But I wonder why - if the transaction can be fake successful in the rest of the cases, why not when consumable. So part of the question is - should I validate consumable purchases?

If the answer is yes - I read validation should be unique for the app and not just some generic solution. Some client side solutions I've found [here](https://www.objc.io/issues/17-security/receipt-validation/) and [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/9257-in-app-purchases-receipt-validation-tutorial). I wonder if't is okay just to use one of those or this would be not secure enough (considering it won't be unique, I don't expect anyone to examine them). Or is it better and more secure for this to be done server side?

I hope these questions are not too broad and thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: As with anything related to security the effort you spend to protect something is proportional to its value and/or how likely someone is to take it. You need to device the impact of someone faking your IAP. Best practice for consumable is for your server to validate the purchase and update a balance that it holds in the user's account. Then anything they do on the device can be overwritten by the server. This also allows the user to share their purchased balance between their devices

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks a lot for your input! If you post this as an answer I'll accept it.